# New Toshiba P300 3TB hard drive produces strange sounds on startup & more

Tags: hard-drive, audio, clicking-sound

So less than a month ago, I bought a new 3TB HDD for my PC, namely the Toshiba P300 HDWD130. Right from the start it has been making strange noises (beeps and slight clicks or crackles) on startup after it spins up, as well as making that same beep every few minutes (or even less, like 30 seconds) during regular PC usage.

I narrowed the latter down to aggressive power management of the drive and I managed to disable APM (Advanced Power Management) permanently via some Windows Registry hacks so the HDD doesn't spin down and make that sound constantly. However, the noises are obviously still present each time I power up my PC and I'm worried that the drive will fail prematurely, as I have never experienced anything similar with any of my older HDDs. Maybe I'm wrong and the sounds this particular HDD makes are perfectly fine and don't indicate that there's anything wrong with it, but I would like to get input of someone with more experience than me.

Here's a [voice recording](https://vocaroo.com/168zP1l91UwG) of the startup process (the sounds I was trying to describe start around the 0:06 mark).

It is worth mentioning that neither CrystalDiskInfo nor Hard Disk Sentinel report any issues with the drive, and its health is apparently 100%. I have also tried plugging the SATA cables from my other HDD to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is the noisiest HDD i ever bought. Very noise while spinning, louder than any fan in my computer. I did switch off APM and set a value of 35 sec for PM in HDDScan

Comment: I am actually finding it very quiet during normal use, even when under load (well, at least now that I've turned off APM permanently). The only problem are the weird sounds it makes when powering up (e.g. when waking PC up from sleep or booting) and after that it's practically silent. Do you also have those weird "crackles" after the 0:06 mark in my recording?

Answer (score -1):

The click at the end is the sound of the head being parked because disk isn't being used. It is exact same click you will hear repeatedly once your HDD starts failing. "Saving power" (less than 1W) excuse is really poor, these HDD's are designed to fail fast, a sound of crappy disk if you will.

The "problem" is you aren't using it enough... Or you aren't using it infrequently enough, it seems like these disks are manufactured for bursty use such as movies, listening to music and furiously scrolling through your photo collections, because for the period you're watching a movie, the disk will be asked to do a lot of small reads that keep the hard drive constantly fully active because video players don't read entire movie into memory at once, then when you're done, it will almost immediately park its head and save power.

I "solved" the problem of my disk parking every *60s* (this is with APM 254, ridiculous) with this script on my Linux system, it keeps pinging the disk controller to start the disk, which resets its parking timeout if the disk was already started and had its head unparked.

```
while :
do
    sdparm --command=start /dev/<your disk id here>
    sleep 54 # could be closer to 60, but it's better to be safe
done
```

https://github.com/m2adel/PingHD Seems to be made with same idea, but judging from the code it reads/writes files instead so some small wear on disk is inevitable.

Answer (score -2):

Have similar random clicking sound on Toshiba [DT01ACA200](8years old) and Toshiba P300 [HDWD130UZSVA](new, just bought) under Windows 7 and 10. First and second disks have good health status and smart via diagnostic software. And i dont feel any issues in work.

I solved "random clicking" through HardDiskSentinel, i set maximum level performance and power consuption (254) value of APM, its mean **Disable APM**, and i set "Load with Windows" in Preferences of HardDiskSentinel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6QV9.jpg

PS Want to hear experience other owners about this this sounds on toshiba's or official explanations from Toshiba.

PPS So this "clicking" sound its autoparking heads?

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. This is a Question and Answer site. This isn't the right place to "hear experience other owners about this..." except insofar as you can read the question posted and see other's answers to them.

Comment: Ok. I am new, and do not know this rule. But why -1? I am anwer and share my expirence.

Comment: The Help section has very good information in it, and as you are new, you were likely shown a LOT of different information referring you to it and explaining what this site is and how it works as you tried to pot this.

Comment: So its you downvoting my post?

Comment: “I am anwer and share my expirence.” This is not an answer. You are simply saying you have the same problem. This site is a question and answer forum. You need to post questions as questions and answers as answers. That is why this question was downvoted. My advice in general? Return the drive and get a new one; maybe from another manufacturer.